# Way to asynchronously load Google Translate widget for your website?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-translate

Is there a way to asynchronously load Google Translate widget for your website?

I tried putting this on the bottom of my page, but the #google_translate_element container was still empty.

```
<!-- Asynchronous Google Translate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,bg,bn,de,el,eo,es,en,fr,hi,id,it,iw,ja,ko,pl,pt,ru,th,tr,vi,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-1234-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
}

(function() {
  var googleTranslateScript = document.createElement('script');
  googleTranslateScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  googleTranslateScript.async = true;
  googleTranslateScript.src = '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild( googleTranslateScript );
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have several problems in your code. But your basic idea is sound.

Assuming that `<div id="google_translate_element"></div>` is defined before the the script tag, the following should work:

```
<!-- Asynchronous Google Translate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',
      includedLanguages: 'ar,bg,bn,de,el,eo,es,en,fr,hi,id,it,iw,ja,ko,pl,pt,ru,th,tr,vi,zh-CN',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
      gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-37652767-1'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }

  var googleTranslateScript = document.createElement('script');
  googleTranslateScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  googleTranslateScript.async = true;
  googleTranslateScript.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild(googleTranslateScript);
</script>
```

At least it worked for me when I placed it all in a HTML file and loaded into chrome.

Of course it would be possible to place the `var`declaration and following lines in a `$(document).ready` function (or in some other manner if you do not use jQuery). Then the order between `div` and `script` would no longer be of consequence.

Comment: Thanks. Can you "peer review" my edit? I improved the src to be just // rather than http://. That way it works with HTTPS too. It's a neat trick.

Comment: I don't have the rep yet to review, otherwise I would. Ahh - `//` didn't work for me, but that was probably because I didn't have it on a server.

Comment: This looks good actually! I'd recommend using defer instead of async though because of IE support.

Comment: Well, I did a bit of reading up and it turns out that neither defer nor async are currently supported in Opera - and IE 4 and upwards until IE9 use a non-standard implementation of defer, so it probably won't work as the specs say anyways. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility) you can see browser compatibility for the script tag and its attributes.